# What is the best way to save/generate Base64 string?

Tags: java, android, base64, password-protection

I need to protect Key string (inside the code) in my application. What is the best way to do it?
Why pure initialization is not good?
That is, does my example bad?

```
final String KEY="aDvT36YYfpE5Ewn-DfvD";
```

How I have to save and restore this line?

Comment: do you need to store it even after the application shut down?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. try this if it helps

Comment: yes. i need it. But what is the best to save temporary (one session) String?

Comment: Raghunandan, this is not what i want. "hi", "hello" in your link are given as pure string. Is this protected way?

Comment: @trololo you can use the code to encrypt your string. hi is the string encrypted.

Comment: @trololo the string "hello" is the one encrypted. so provide which string you want to encrypt. "hi" is just a key. don't worry about salt[]..

Comment: that is , i can use key values as usual string?

Comment: i haven't tested anything other than usual string. but give it a try.

Comment: I confused in-app billing sample where I read this: "In a real app, either hide this on your server or compose it of multiple concat Strings so it's not so easy to find"