# Encryption & Decryption algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, encryption, java-me

I am working on mobile product. We are using the data in `xml document`. In order to keep our data secure we need an **encryption algorithm**(but we don't want the existing algorithm to import)

Can u give me some steps to encrypt the data.(*if code example is most welcome*).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884 . here's a implementation for encryption and decryption. Here's the android developer blog for the same http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

Comment: if you got the answer, try to accept that.

Comment: It is always best to use ready made encryption algorithm, than to make your own. The main reason is - encryption turns meaningful things into garbage by definition. And it is very difficult to evaluate it. Only dedicated expert, working for quite a long time, can tell if your scheme produces good enough garbage. So even if you do produce your own algorithm, you wouldn't have any guarantees unless you publish it for a review.

Comment: Please see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To be more secure, you have to do with your own secret key. Try to use this code

```
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance();
 // get the names of all keys created by our app
 String[] keyNames = ks.saw("");

 // store a symmetric key in the keystore
 SecretKey key = Crypto.generateKey();
 boolean success = ks.put("secretKey1", key.getEncoded());
 // check if operation succeeded and get error code if not
 if (!success) {
    int errorCode = ks.getLastError();
    throw new RuntimeException("Keystore error: " + errorCode); 
 }

 // get a key from the keystore
 byte[] keyBytes = ks.get("secretKey1");
 SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

 // delete a key
 boolean success = ks.delete("secretKey1");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own encryption scheme, be prepared to embark on a research project. You can use any of standard encryption algorithms like AES/DES etc, with your private keys that are sufficiently long and difficult to crack.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string PassEncrypt(string Password)
{
    // Encrypting the password entered by User
    // ======================================================
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password));
    byte[] result = md5.Hash;
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return strBuilder.ToString();
    // ======================================================
}
```

### OR

You may refer on this links :

[developer.motorala.com](http://developer.motorola.com/docs/using_the_advanced_encryption_standard_in_android/)

[codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/secure-aes-encryption-and-decryption-in-android)

[android snippets](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings)

[java-tips.org](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.crypto/encryption-and-decryption-using-symmetric-2.html)

Comment: That's hashing, not encryption.