# RSA Encryption/Decryption Convert Byte[] to String and Vice Versa

Tags: android, string, arrays, rsa

I am workin on a Rsa encrypt/decrypt application on android.I create and save my public/private key to sharedpreferences.I am reading them and using for encrypt/decrypt with this code block:

```
public String RSADecrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    privateKey = getPrivateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    return new String(cipherData,"UTF-16BE");               
    }

public String RSAEncrypt(String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    publicKey = getPublicKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());           
    return new String(cipherData,"UTF-16BE");
    }
```

Now, for example i am trying to encrypt "BAHADIR", it writes to EditText meaningless words. I used "UTF-8", "UTF-16", "UTF-16LE", "UTF16BE" and "ISO-8859-1" but everytime i get meaningless words again, not same but all of them meaningless. Where am i wrong, can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this and this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html. Might help. (AES).

Comment: I tryied these convert method but does not work for me, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't convert binary data to a String. You can, for example, encode it with Base64 encoding if you want it as a printable String.

Try the following:

```
import android.util.Base64

... 

byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
String cipherString = Base64.encodeBytes(cipherData);
```

Comment: For Base64.DEFAULT, it says "DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field".I am working 2.1 API.Is it a problem?

Comment: Now i detect that, in my Basa64 there is no attribute like encodeToString

Comment: there is no encodeBytes also. Iam using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 library for Base64, is it right?

Comment: Ok.i change my library with android.util.Base64 and now it accepts encodeToString.Now there is meaning words, thanks yonili.Please update code again :)