# Encryption in Android equivalent to php's MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Tags: php, android, encryption

I am using the below php code for encryption:

---

```
$enc_request = base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                 $this->_app_key, 
                 json_encode($request_params), 
                 MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)
);
```

---

Now trying to encrypt the in android and getting the different encrypted string. Below is the android code:

---

```
public void enc(){
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey("my_key".getBytes());
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal("my_message".getBytes());
    String result=Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(256, sr); 
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}
```

---

Could any one help me, where I am wrong? And get same correct encrypted string in android too.

Comment: Place of "Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")" this I've also tried to "AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding" for algo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this if it helps

Comment: Hi Raghu, I don't have iv, so I remove the iv parameter form init() but still getting different encrypted string. I can't understand the where could could I used iv although I have only a secret key/salt. to encrypt as in php code. please review.

Comment: i just posted a link if it helps use that as a reference if not useful ignore it

Comment: @Raghu, where is link?

Comment: see the second comment.

Comment: What do you mean, where do you go wrong? You just copied some code from the internet and for PHP and Android and expected it to work. That's where you mainly go wrong.

Comment: Learn about block modes of encryption, padding modes and the actual AES algorithm. Currently you are not even using AES in PHP, and you are using a flawed key derivation mechanism in Android. Except using ECB mode encryption in Java, everything else is wrong.

Comment: @owlstead, Really I was even not aware about the mcrypt_encrypt() methods and how it works internally. Although, last day I read about padding, block and different encryption modes. It helping me to explore my ideas. Thanks

Comment: @Pankaj I will try and implement a compatibility method in Java, but to do that I would have to repeat the mistakes PHP makes, and I would not really want those to spread around. It's much better to write a wrapper library around mcrypt_encrypt() that removes the mistakes that were made...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a `main` method in Java using Bouncy Castle to show the inner workings of `mcrypt_encrypt()` used in your code sample.

This is mainly to show other developers that PHP's `mcrypt_encrypt()` is a very dangerous method to use. It won't fail much, but that is because it rather continues where it should have stopped long ago. For instance, it adds or removes values from the key. It emits a warning when it does do this, but it won't directly show in the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {

    // just some constants
    boolean ENCRYPT = true;
    boolean DECRYPT = false;

    // the key is either in binary in PHP or a string (dynamic isn't it?), lets assume ASCII
    byte[] givenKey = args[0].getBytes(Charset.forName("ASCII"));

    // determine the key size dynamically, somebody thought this was a good idea...
    // NOTE: PHP will emit a warning if the key size is larger, but will simply use the
    // largest key size otherwise
    final int keysize;
    if (givenKey.length <= 128 / Byte.SIZE) {
        keysize = 128;
    } else if (givenKey.length <= 192 / Byte.SIZE) {
        keysize = 192;
    } else {
        keysize = 256;
    }

    // create a 256 bit key by adding zero bytes to the decoded key
    byte[] keyData = new byte[keysize / Byte.SIZE];
    System.arraycopy(givenKey, 0, keyData, 0, Math.min(givenKey.length, keyData.length));
    KeyParameter key = new KeyParameter(keyData);

    // create a Rijndael cipher with 256 bit block size, this is not AES
    BlockCipher rijndael = new RijndaelEngine(256);

    // use a padding method that only works on data that cannot end with zero valued bytes
    ZeroBytePadding c = new ZeroBytePadding();

    // use ECB mode encryption, which should never be used
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher pbbc = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(rijndael, c);

    // initialize the cipher using the key (no need for an IV, this is ECB)
    pbbc.init(ENCRYPT, key);

    // create a plain text byte array
    byte[] plaintext = args[1].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8"));

    // create a buffer for the ciphertext
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[pbbc.getOutputSize(plaintext.length)];

    int offset = 0;
    offset += pbbc.processBytes(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length, ciphertext, offset);
    offset += pbbc.doFinal(ciphertext, offset);

    // show the ciphertext
    System.out.println(new String(Hex.encode(ciphertext), Charset.forName("ASCII")));

    // reverse the encryption
    pbbc.init(DECRYPT, key);
    byte[] decrypted = new byte[pbbc.getOutputSize(ciphertext.length)];
    offset = 0;
    offset += pbbc.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, decrypted, offset);
    offset += pbbc.doFinal(decrypted, offset);

    // this will probably print out correctly, but it isn't actually correct
    System.out.println(new String(decrypted, Charset.forName("UTF8")));

    // check out the zero's at the end
    System.out.println(new String(Hex.encode(decrypted), Charset.forName("UTF8")));

    // so lets make it a bit shorter... the PHP way
    // note that in PHP, the string may *not* contain a null terminator
    // add it yourself before printing the string
    System.out.println(new String(decrypted, Charset.forName("UTF8")).replaceAll("\\x00+$", ""));
}
```

---

**Warning**: the above code contains `ZeroBytePadding`. I later discovered that there is a difference between Bouncy Castle and PHP in this respect: Bouncy Castle expects that you always have to pad, while PHP doesn't. So Bouncy adds 1..n bytes while PHP adds 0..(n-1) bytes, where n is the block size (32 bytes for Rijndael-256/256). So you may have to do the padding/unpadding yourself; be sure to test the edge cases!

Comment: It's working fine for key length 16 or less, but once I use the key of length more than 16, it's showing misleading strings. Is I need to look at KeyParameter or suggest what else? I tried what I'ld. Thanks

Comment: It may be that it is cutting it to 128 bit instead of upgrading the key. I programmed this out of the top of my head, I'll check.

Comment: Ah, very simple, it was a typo for the compare `<= 128` was used instead of `<= 192`. Got confused, looked it up in source and my initial implementation was otherwise fine. PHP's implementation is way too permissive of course.

Comment: uhh, now it just fun...!! Thanks owlstead for every things that I learn from you...!!

Comment: This is the only example that works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HoangTran Added a warning, the code may be overdue for a rewrite.