# JAVA a reliable equivalent for php's MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Tags: java, php, encryption, rijndael

I need to access some data that used PHP encryption. The PHP encryption is like this.

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($cipher), $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

As value of $text they pass the time() function value which will be different each time that the method is called in.  I have implemented this in Java. Like this,

```
public static String md5(String string) {
    byte[] hash;

    try {
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Huh, MD5 should be supported?", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Huh, UTF-8 should be supported?", e);
    }

    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);

    for (byte b : hash) {
        int i = (b & 0xFF);
        if (i < 0x10) hex.append('0');
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString(i));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}

public static byte[] rijndael_256(String text, byte[] givenKey) throws DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException, IOException{
    final int keysize;

    if (givenKey.length <= 192 / Byte.SIZE) {
        keysize = 192;
    } else {
        keysize = 256;
    }

    byte[] keyData = new byte[keysize / Byte.SIZE];
    System.arraycopy(givenKey, 0, keyData, 0, Math.min(givenKey.length, keyData.length));
    KeyParameter key = new KeyParameter(keyData);
    BlockCipher rijndael = new RijndaelEngine(256);
    ZeroBytePadding c = new ZeroBytePadding();
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher pbbc = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(rijndael, c);
    pbbc.init(true, key);

    byte[] plaintext = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[pbbc.getOutputSize(plaintext.length)];
    int offset = 0;
    offset += pbbc.processBytes(plaintext, 0, plaintext.length, ciphertext, offset);
    offset += pbbc.doFinal(ciphertext, offset);
    return ciphertext;
}


public static String encrypt(String text, String secretKey) throws Exception {


    byte[] givenKey = String.valueOf(md5(secretKey)).getBytes(Charset.forName("ASCII"));

    byte[] encrypted = rijndael_256(text,givenKey);

    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
}
```

I have referred this answer when creating MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 method."
[Encryption in Android equivalent to php's MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101545/encryption-in-android-equivalent-to-phps-mcrypt-rijndael-256)
"I have used apache codec for Base64.Here's how I call the encryption function,

```
long time= System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
String encryptedTime = EncryptionUtils.encrypt(String.valueOf(time), secretkey);
```

The problem is sometimes the output is not similar to PHP but sometimes it works fine.
I think that my MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 method is unreliable.
I want to know where I went wrong and find a reliable method so that I can always get similar encrypted string as to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be the `ZeroBytePadding`. The one of Bouncy always adds/removes at least one byte with value zero (a la PKCS5Padding, 1 to 16 bytes of padding) but the one of PHP only pads until the first block boundary is encountered (0 to 15 bytes of padding). I've discussed this with David of the legion of Bouncy Castle, but the PHP zero byte padding is an extremely ill fit for the way Bouncy does padding, so currently you'll have to do this yourself, and use the cipher without padding.

Of course, as a real solution, rewrite the PHP part to use AES (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`), CBC mode encryption, HMAC authentication, a real Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF, e.g. PBKDF2 or bcrypt) and PKCS#7 compatible padding instead of this insecure, incompatible code. Alternatively, go for OpenSSL compatibility or a known secure container format.

Comment: I once tried to create a similar class that tried to mimic all of `mcrypt_encrypt` but in the end I gave up in disgust. I did rewrite the sample code of `mcrypt_encrypt` to keep people from falling in the same trap though.

Comment: I am grateful for what you have done.I am creating a java framework similar to an existing PHP framework. There are many clients who already use the PHP framework. I will check what I can do to change it to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128. Thanks a lot.