# How to Encrypt And decrypt UTF-8 in JAVA or Android?

Tags: java, android, json, encryption, public-key-encryption

I use This Algorithm for Encrypt and Decrypt data in android. But when use utf-8 charater ..this error is displayed  : [encrypt] data not block size aligned.

I use this Algorithm for Encrypt and Decrypt : https://snipt.net/raw/ee573b6957b7416f28aa560ead71c3a2/?nice

my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(ServerIP.frooshgah_URL);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();



        try {
            json.put("UserId", "0s");
            json.put("N_frooshgah", N_frooshgah);
            json.put("N_masol", N_masol);
            json.put("N_makan", N_makan);
            json.put("address", address);
            json.put("tel", tel);
            json.put("time_baz", time_baz);
            json.put("time_baste", time_baste);
            json.put("tavzihat", tavzihat);
            json.put("tag", tag);
            json.put("categori", "پوشاک");
            json.put("city", city);
            json.put("lat", lat);
            json.put("long", Long);

        } catch (JSONException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
        String encrypted = "";
        try {

            encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex(mcrypt.encrypt(json.toString()));
            //encrypted = encryption.hexToString(json.toString(), 2);
              //key = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
            //encrypted=Crypto.encrypt(json.toString(),key);


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to Resolve this Problem?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this if it helps

Comment: Whoever wrote the Mcrypt code made some beginner's mistake such as assuming that each character will be one byte when converted into a binary representation and using some platform default text encoding (which is likely different on the platform you send the encrypted data to).

Comment: i want send data to php yii framework and Encrpted

Comment: Try changing the `getBytes()` occurences (I 've counted 3 of them) with `getBytes("UTF8")`.

Comment: `"پوشاک"` is `D9 BE D9 88 D8 B4 D8 A7 DA A9` in hex'd utf-8 bytes. I.e. 10 bytes while `String#length()` says 5. -> Fix the `padString` method and make it use the number of bytes instead of string length. Also do hardcode UTF-8 as above. MCrypt should work then.

Comment: How to Change MCrypt class?

Comment: File a bug report. Ask them to implement a padding scheme other than zero byte padding while you are at it. Note that mcrypt in PHP is arguably the worst crypro library I have ever encountered. The fact that the underlying c source code is not maintained at all is just the beginning if the problems.

Comment: Not trying to step on any toes but your tag "public-key-encryption" is not correct because this is symmetric key encryption where only one key is used to both encrypt and decrypt the data as opposed to using a public/private keypair for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see the `MCrypt` class your using provides source code. Download the source code and add it to your project and modify the `padString(string)` method to this:

```
private static String padString(String source){
  char paddingChar = ' ';
  int size = 16;
  int x = source.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).length % size;
  int padLength = size - x;

  for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
  {
          source += paddingChar;
  }

  return source;
}
```

This will allow the code to execute while using `UTF-8` as a `charset`. If you want to "improve" the library to support mutliple charsets, consider adding a `charset` parameter into the `encrypt`/`decrypt` methods of the class.

Comment: excuse me...error in Decrypt :    java.lang.Exception: [decrypt] unable to parse '
<' as integer

Comment: @srfarzad Probably originating from the hexToBytes method inside the MCrypt class. A hexadecimal value can only contain the characters 0-9 and a, b, c, d, e, f. Failing to parse '<' suggests your input string is invalid.