# how to utf-8 Encrypt / Decrypt in Android

Tags: android, encryption, utf-8

Hi i want to Encrypt string and this work good but when i want to use for utf_8 persian this not work. i use this tutorial:

http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php.html

. and my main activity code is :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String value="سلام";

    try {
        MCrypt mcrypt = new MCrypt();
        String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt( value ) );
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+encrypted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String decrypted = new String(mcrypt.decrypt( encrypted ));
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+decrypted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

i read this post [How to Encrypt And decrypt UTF-8 in JAVA or Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279818/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-utf-8-in-java-or-android) but not help me
thanks for your helps guys

Comment: If there is anything more stupid than PHP + mcrypt out there when it comes to cryptography then it is Android snippets. But back to the question: can you check if the result of `mcrypt.decrypt( encrypted )` matches the result of `mcrypt.encrypt( value )` in bytes? There should be something as Array.compare or you can compare the byte arrays encoded as hexadecimals. Note that using CBC is not secure when it comes to client - server communication (i.e. when used for transport security).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Don't you think it might be a tad misleading to say that CBC is not secure for transport security?  Sure, without an MAC it can be modified, but CBC **can** be secure when used correctly with other cryptographic systems.

Comment: @LukePark I only see CBC here. I'm not sure about plaintext oracle attacks but certainly without any additional measures you should not expect integrity/authenticity of the messages send. Besides that, a static IV (change it!), padding with spaces what else can go wrong?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I wasn't implying that this particular implementation is secure, clearly it isn't.  It just seemed like a bit of a generalization is all!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this specific error is in:

```
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
```

on the PHP site; I don't see any specific character encoding used to encode the `$str` value.