# AES 512 bit encryption with Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

Is it possible to do **AES 512-bit Encryption** with Android app for user credential?
Has Anyone tried this?
I search a lot about this but did not get the Help.

Any Help is Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this if it helps

Comment: First of all, you should not be using AES for storing user credentials, second, there is no such thing as AES-512.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there is no such thing as AES-512 bit encryption. There is only AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256 bits encryption specified by NIST in
[FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Look at this**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class AesFileIo {
//    private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;

    public AesFileIo(byte[] aesKey, byte[] iv) {
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    }

    public String decrypt(String text) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] decordedValue =  Base64.decode(text,Base64.DEFAULT);
            String decryptedValue = new String(cipher.doFinal(decordedValue),"UTF-8");
            Log.e("decrypted Value :",decryptedValue);
            return decryptedValue; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        String encryptedValue=null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM); 
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] encValue = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encValue,Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return encryptedValue;
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
public static byte[] iv = { '0', '0','0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'b', 'i', 'r', 'a', 'j', 'z', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'a', 'd', 'i', 'y', 'a', 'r' };
AesFileIo aes = new AesFileIo(keyValue, iv);
String encrypetedText = aes.encrypt(str);
String decryptedText = aes.decrypt(encrypetedText);

System.out.println("EncrypetedText : " + encrypetedText);
System.out.println("DecryptedText : " + decryptedText);
```

Comment: `decordedValue` -> `decodedValue`? `String.getBytes()` -> `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` ?

Comment: Your name has too little entropy too. 16 characters makes for 128 bit keys, and less than 128 bit entropy of course. Nowhere near 512 bit AES, if that existed.