# AES - Java (Android) support guaranteed?

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I cannot find anywhere if every Java platform implementation must come with an AES implementation too.

I want to use the following code on Android:

```
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
 decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
```

However, I cannot find if "AES" is guaranteed to be implemented (like the "SHA-1" algorithm is guaranteed to be implemented on every Java platform as per this quote:

*"Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard MessageDigest algorithms:
MD5
SHA-1
SHA-256"*

(Font: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

Does anybody know if an AES implementation is guaranteed to come with Java (or even with Android, which is where I want to use it)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue/17080884#17080884. check this if it helps

Comment: Thank you for replying but the link provided, and its sublinks, don't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java, look in the [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) section of the JCA standard names.  It lists AES as one of the standard encryption algorithms.  Also look in the [Implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#impl) sections of the same document.  In there, it lists the minimal encryption transformations required for all Java runtimes.  The list includes:

- AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
- AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)
- AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
- AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)

So, AES is guaranteed to be supported in either CBC or ECB mode with either PKCS5 or no padding.  The only key size guaranteed to be supported is 128-bit.

Now, Android is technically not a Java runtime so is not bound to the JCA requirements.  However, most likely AES is supported in one mode or another because it is included as an example in [Android's API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).  To get a full list of available encryption transformations, use the following code:

```
public void ListSupportedAlgorithms() {
String result = "";

// get all the providers
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();

for (int p = 0; p < providers.length; p++) {
    // get all service types for a specific provider
    Set<Object> ks = providers[p].keySet();
    Set<String> servicetypes = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (Iterator<Object> it = ks.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String k = it.next().toString();
        k = k.split(" ")[0];
        if (k.startsWith("Alg.Alias."))
            k = k.substring(10);

        servicetypes.add(k.substring(0, k.indexOf('.')));
    }

    // get all algorithms for a specific service type
    int s = 1;
    for (Iterator<String> its = servicetypes.iterator(); its.hasNext();) {
        String stype = its.next();
        Set<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (Iterator<Object> it = ks.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String k = it.next().toString();
        k = k.split(" ")[0];
        if (k.startsWith(stype + "."))
            algorithms.add(k.substring(stype.length() + 1));
        else if (k.startsWith("Alg.Alias." + stype +"."))
            algorithms.add(k.substring(stype.length() + 11));
    }

    int a = 1;
    for (Iterator<String> ita = algorithms.iterator(); ita.hasNext();) {
        result += ("[P#" + (p + 1) + ":" + providers[p].getName() + "]" +
                   "[S#" + s + ":" + stype + "]" +
                   "[A#" + a + ":" + ita.next() + "]\n");
        a++;
    }

    s++;
}
}
```

(copied from [Android Encryption with the Android Cryptography API](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html))

There should be several AES transformations in that list.

Comment: Great answer Brent. Thank you. However, the link you provided is related to Java 7. I searched the same thing on Java 6 and found the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#impl As you can see, in the Java 6 docs, AES is listed as "recommended". Once Android does not use Java 7 (yet) I guess my question still remains opened.

Comment: Also, I want to avoid the check at Runtime to see if AES is available. So far, I've tested my code in 5 devices and all of them supported AES (with an 128 bits key), however, I am still to find a solid reference to back my guess AES is always supported.

Comment: Once KitKat now supports Java 7 (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7) I believe it is safe to assume from now on that AES will always be supported (at least the modes described in the official link you provided). I am accepting your answer now.