# AES Encryption Decryption Algorithm in Android

Tags: android, algorithm, encryption, aes

**I
 am trying to encrypt and decrypt my data using AES Algorithm in 
Android. 
This is my code**

```
  package com.example.aesandroidsecurity;

    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    //import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Cipher cipher;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
    private String SecretKey = "1234567890123456";  

    Button encrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button decrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);    
    EditText data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    String plainText = data.getText().toString();

    byte[] encrypted = null;
    byte[] decrypted = null;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];

        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");                    
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());           
        }       
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        encrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+encrypted, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });     

        decrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
                    decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
                }       
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+decrypted, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

**
When I try to run my application, my application stops and 
I am getting following errors in logcat. 
Plz help me...**

```
    02-27 13:59:42.806: E/Trace(1903): error opening trace file: No such
 file or directory (2)
    02-27 13:59:43.296: D/AndroidRuntime(1903): Shutting down VM
    02-27 13:59:43.345: W/dalvikvm(1903): threadid=1: thread exiting 
with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.aesandroidsecurity/com.example.aesandroidsecurity.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903): Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
com.example.aesandroidsecurity.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)

    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

    02-27 13:59:43.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1903):     ... 11 more
    02-27 13:59:48.845: I/Process(1903): Sending signal. PID: 1903 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is  `MainActivity.java` line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these must be in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
Button encrypt; 
Button decrypt;     
EditText data ;
String plainText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button encrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button decrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);    
EditText data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current infalted layout. So you need to initialize views after setting the layout to the Activity.

Also get Text from editText in onResume

or

On Button click

```
plainText = data.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I did that and its working.Thanks a lot! But now there is problem with encryption and decryption, specially in decrypting data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    Button encrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button decrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);    
    EditText data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    String plainText = data.getText().toString();

}
```

You are calling `findViewById()` outside of `onCreate()`, so none of those Views have been inflated and they do not exist yet. Thus `findViewById()` returns null for each of those views, and `data.getText()` will throw the NullPointerException you see in your logs.

Comment: I did that and its working.Thanks a lot! But there is problem with encryption and decryption, specially in decrypting data.

Comment: @user3360750 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079579/aes-algo-decryption-issue